# set_bad function not perform correctly in CARTOPY

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, colormap, cartopy

I'm using cartopy to draw data inside a map, but when I set bad color to gray, the map does not perform correctly, however if I set bad color to fully transparent as Userwarning suggests, the bad color does not show at all

The module I'm using is:

| Module name | version |
| --- | --- |
| PYTHON | 3.10.6 |
| numpy | 1.23.4 |
| cartopy | 0.21.0 |
| matplotlib | 3.6.2 |
| xarray | 2022.11.0 |

I try:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# set style
mpl.style.use("seaborn-v0_8-ticks")

# construct fake data:
sig = np.sin(np.radians(np.linspace(-90, 90, 192)))
sig = np.tile(sig, [288, 1]).T
darr = xr.DataArray(
    sig,
    dims=("lat", "lon"),
    coords={
        "lat": np.linspace(-90, 90, 192),
        "lon": np.linspace(0, 360, 288),
    },
)

# manually set the bad values to nan
darr[100:200, 100:200] = np.nan

cm = plt.get_cmap("RdBu_r")

# set the bad values to gray, get user warning
# and half the map is set to gray
cm.set_bad("gray")

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(
    111,
    projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0),
)
ax1.coastlines()
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(darr["lon"], darr["lat"])
ax1.pcolormesh(
    lons, lats, darr, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=cm
)


# if set bad color to fully transparent
# the bad color is not shown at all
cm.set_bad("gray", alpha=0.0)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(
    111,
    projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0),
)
ax1.coastlines()
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(darr["lon"], darr["lat"])
ax1.pcolormesh(
    lons, lats, darr, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=cm
)
```

dont set transparency, get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3F9W.png)
set to fully transparent, get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13lce.png)
How can I set bad color in cartopy correctly?

Comment: Using transparency and setting `ax1.set_facecolor("gray")` could be a potential workaround, unless you need to overplot multiple datasets. Another workaround could be to not plot the elements touching the dateline, eg first roll the data to -180/180 and then plot only -179/179. In the end I think what you want is imply not supported at the moment, although it's probably not something that's theoretically impossible to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am indeed using facecolor settings to solve my problems, and it works just like I expected! Hope cartopy team can fix this set_bad thing soon.